# Python3 Sha256: TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, typeerror

Every time I run my code I get the same error and don't know how to fix it.

Script 1:

```
from firebase import firebase
import hashlib as hash

#define database to use as a link
fb = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://proxima-database.firebaseio.com')

def append_data(directory, key, value):
    #add data to database, specifying directory, and key:value
    append = fb.post(directory, {key : value})
    print(append)

def fetch_data(directory):
    #grab data from specific directory
    fetch = fb.get(directory, None).encode("utf-8")
    print(fetch)
```

Script 2:

```
import hashlib as hash
import DataFetch as df

directory = '/prox'
dataToHash = df.fetch_data(directory)

hashedData = hash.sha256(dataToHash)

append = df.append_data(directory, 'John', hashedData)
print(append)
```

Output:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 "/Users/User/Desktop/Programming Folder/Data Hashing Function.py"
b'123'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Desktop/Programming Folder/Data Hashing Function.py", line 7, in <module>
    hashedData = hash.sha256(dataToHash)
TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required
```

I dont understand what to change? I've looked at many similar problems but can't figure out how they correlate to mine. Thank you!

Comment: How would I serialize it exactly?

Comment: `print()` ist not a `return`. You have to use `return` to get a value out of a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fetch_data` function does not return a value.  If a python function does not explicitly return a value then `None` is returned.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha256(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required
```

The problem can be fixed by having `fetch_data` return the data that it fetches:

```
def fetch_data(directory):
    #grab data from specific directory
    fetch = fb.get(directory, None).encode("utf-8")
    return fetch
```